# Read from text file with multiple delimiters and organize into objects

Tags: c#, delimiter

I've a text file that that uses | and "-----" as delimiters. I was wondering how to approach this. I have a main class, and 3 classes, Song.cs, Movie.cs, and Book.cs. I need to be able to read from the text file, and sort each media type into the correct object along with the media's title, author, year, and description (description is encrypted in rot13 in case people are wondering, which I already know how to decrypt). Text sample and code below. Thanks for your time.

Textfile Sample:

```
BOOK|The Fellowship of the Ring|1954|J.R.R. Tolkien
Fnheba, gur Qnex Ybeq, unf tngurerq gb uvz nyy gur Evatf bs Cbjre rkprcg bar - gur Bar Evat gung ehyrf gurz nyy - juvpu unf snyyra vagb gur unaqf bs gur uboovg Ovyob Onttvaf. Lbhat Sebqb Onttvaf svaqf uvzfrys snprq jvgu na vzzrafr gnfx jura Ovyob ragehfgf gur Evat gb uvf pner. Sebqb zhfg znxr n crevybhf wbhearl npebff Zvqqyr-rnegu gb gur Penpxf bs Qbbz, gurer gb qrfgebl gur Evat naq sbvy gur Qnex Ybeq va uvf rivy checbfr.
-----
SONG|Fly Me to the Moon|1964|It Might as Well be Swing|Frank Sinatra
-----
MOVIE|The Princess Bride|1987|Rob Reiner
N xvaqyl tenaqsngure fvgf qbja jvgu uvf tenaqfba naq ernqf uvz n orqgvzr fgbel. Gur fgbel vf bar gung unf orra cnffrq qbja guebhtu sebz sngure gb fba sbe trarengvbaf. Nf gur tenaqsngure ernqf gur fgbel, gur npgvba pbzrf nyvir. Gur fgbel vf n pynffvp gnyr bs ybir naq nqiragher nf gur ornhgvshy Ohggrephc vf xvqanccrq naq uryq ntnvafg ure jvyy va beqre gb zneel gur bqvbhf Cevapr Uhzcreqvapx, naq Jrfgyrl (ure puvyqubbq ornh, abj erghearq nf gur Qernq Cvengr Eboregf) nggrzcgf gb fnir ure. Ba gur jnl ur zrrgf na nppbzcyvfurq fjbeqfzna naq n uhtr, fhcre fgebat tvnag, obgu bs jubz orpbzr uvf pbzcnavbaf va uvf dhrfg. Gurl zrrg n srj onq thlf nybat gur jnl gb erfphr Ohggrephc.
-----
BOOK|The Two Towers|1954|J.R.R. Tolkien
Gur Sryybjfuvc jnf fpnggrerq. Fbzr jrer oenpvat ubcryrffyl sbe jne ntnvafg gur napvrag rivy bs Fnheba. Fbzr jrer pbagraqvat jvgu gur gernpurel bs gur jvmneq Fnehzna. Bayl Sebqb naq Fnz jrer yrsg gb gnxr gur npphefrq Evat bs Cbjre gb or qrfgeblrq va Zbeqbe - gur qnex Xvatqbz jurer Fnheba jnf fhcerzr. Gurve thvqr jnf Tbyyhz, qrprvgshy naq yhfgsvyyrq, fynir gb gur pbeehcgvba bs gur Evat.
-----
BOOK|The Return of the King|1955|J.R.R. Tolkien
Nf gur Funqbj bs Zbeqbe tebjf npebff gur ynaq, Nentbea vf erirnyrq nf gur uvqqra urve bs gur napvrag xvatf. Tnaqnys zvenphybhfyl ergheaf naq qrsrngf gur rivy jvmneq, Fnehzna. Fnz yrnirf uvf znfgre sbe qrnq nsgre n onggyr jvgu gur tvnag fcvqre, Furybo; ohg Sebqb vf fgvyy nyvir - va gur unaqf bs gur Bepf. Naq nyy gur juvyr gur nezvrf bs gur Qnex Ybeq ner znffvat - naq gur Bar Evat pbzrf rire pybfre gb gur Penpxf bs Qbbz.
-----
```

```
class Program
{
    private const int MAX_MEDIA_OBJECTS = 100; // Max number of array objects
    private int numberOfMedia = 0; // Counter to keep track of amount
                                   // of media in Data.txt

    private Media[] media = new Media[MAX_MEDIA_OBJECTS];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

    public void ReadData()
    {
        // Opens the Data.txt file for read access
        FileStream mediaFile =
            new FileStream("Data.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader mediaData = new StreamReader(mediaFile);

        string mediaRow; // Holds each media data per row

        while ((mediaRow = mediaData.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] mediaDataSplit = mediaRow.Split('|');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd read lines until you reach your delimiter, then parse those lines

Comment: That's a creative approach, thanks. I never thought of that.

Comment: if your file isn't enormous, it'll be much easier to read it all into memory, like in Sudhakar's answer

Comment: That kind of solution doesn't scale very well.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the File and split it based on the delimeter `-----` to get the rows and then split again using `|` delimeter to get the words in each line.

Try This:

```
string path=@"C:\Data.txt";
var allText = File.ReadAllText(path);
string [] allLines=allText.Split(new[] { "-----" }, 
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var line in allLines)
{
string[] allWords = line.Split(new[] { "|" }, 
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 /*do some thing here*/

 /*do some thing here*/
}
```

Comment: Creative use of split on there! But wouldn't this join the last field of the metadata line and the description?

Answer (score 2):

First, I would make the three classes inherit from a base class `Media`. Each of the subclasses would implement a method `parseMediaInfo(String[] elements)` which take care of the parsing - or implement it in the base class if it's the same for all. Then implement the following:

```
public void ReadData()
{
    // Opens the Data.txt file for read access
    FileStream mediaFile = new FileStream("Data.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader mediaData = new StreamReader(mediaFile);

    string mediaRow; // Holds each media data per row
    Media media = null;
    var list = new List<Media>();
    while ((mediaRow = mediaData.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (mediaRow.startsWith("-----") && media != null) {
            list.add(media);
            media = null;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (media != null) media.parseDescription(mediaRow);
            else {
                string[] mediaDataSplit = mediaRow.Split('|');
                media = constructMediaOfType(mediaDataSplit[0]);
                media.parseMediaInfo(mediaDataSplit);        
            }               
        }           
    }
}

private static Media constructMediaOfType(String type) 
{
    switch (type) {
        case "BOOK": return new Book();
        case "SONG": return new Song();
        case "MOVIE" return new Movie();
        default: throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```